# Use arguments with Jinja2 templates in Operator Extra Link Airflow

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I am trying to create an S3 Operator Extra Link. Its code is the following:

```
class S3Link(BaseOperatorLink):
    name = "S3"

    def get_link(self, operator, dttm):
        if "S3" in operator.task_type:
            return f"https://{operator.s3_bucket}.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{operator.s3_key}"
```

However, usually, I have `s3_bucket` and `s3_key` defined with Jinja2 templates, like the following:

```
    s3_sta_keywords = GoogleDriveToS3Operator(
            task_id="s3_sta_keywords",
            drive_file_id="1ogjkdfalfnadjiowñklasdfk",
            s3_bucket="{{ var.json.get('variables_secret').s3_bucket }}",
            s3_key="airflow" + process_name + "/keywords_{{ ts_nodash }}.csv",
)
```

It's a custom operator that has `s3_key` and `s3_bucket` as template fields and they get rendered correctly, as can be seen in the picture below:
[image]

I have tried to render the fields with:
class S3Link(BaseOperatorLink):
name = "S3"

```
    def get_link(self, operator, dttm):
        if "S3" in operator.task_type:
            @provide_session
            def get_rendered_templates(session):
                return Airflow.rendered_templates(session)

            templates = get_rendered_templates()

            return f"https://{templates.s3_bucket}.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{operator.s3_key}"
```

But it doesn't work, as it is stuck in this state:

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this? Or could the core code of Airflow be modified to have it as a feature?

Comment: Could you also add the full Operator instantiation code?

Comment: I don't understand what code do you want me to add @Emma could you clarify a little bit, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure. I would like to see the whole code of the task instantiation.  like `t1 = XXXOperator(....s3_bucket=...)` where the jinja template is passed.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question with the code

Comment: Sorry, I just realized. My previous questions wasn't relevant.  I think the issue is you cannot have access to `context` in `BaseOperatorLink` as the `BaseOperatorLink` should be static. The rendered template is dynamic and needs to be executed to obtain the contents.   If you can change to Connections instead of variables to set/pass S3 bucket, you might be able to make the S3Link.

Comment: Other thing you can consider is instead of passing jinja with `var.json`, pass `variables_secret` and/or `s3_bucket` as static string to your operator and inside of your custom operator and S3Link, access to the value through `Variable.get()`.

Comment: Thanks Emma. What you suggest doesn't fit my needs, so I guess I have to discard this OperatorLink. Thank you!